# Adding KDE Backports PPA has caused unmet dependencies. How to fix?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kubuntu, ppa, dependencies

I added `ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports` in the usual way, then performed a `dist-upgrade`. It needed to download over gigabyte of files, so I left if for the afternoon. Upon my return, I found that the system had become very unstable and unusable.

I logged in at the console and rebooted it from there and when I got back in, things are somewhat messed up.

I ran `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade` and noticed the following in the output:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kdm
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,227 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,668 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdm:
 kdm depends on kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3); however:
  Version of kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins on system is 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1.
 kde-workspace-data (4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1) breaks kdm (<< 4:4.10.80) and is installed.
  Version of kdm to be configured is 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3.
dpkg: error processing kdm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kubuntu-desktop:
 kubuntu-desktop depends on kdm; however:
  Package kdm is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing kubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                     Errors were encountered while processing:
 kdm
 kubuntu-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ideally I'll like to satisfy the dependencies, so if possible, can someone advise how to do that please. Failing that, please advise how to role-back to previous configuration.

Thanks.

Using Ubuntu 12.04 with Kernel 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu

** UPDATE **

```
peter@pete:~$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kde-workspace-data : Breaks: kdm (< 4:4.10.80) but 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3 is installed
 kdm : Depends: kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3) but 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
peter@pete:~$ 
peter@pete:~$ 
peter@pete:~$ sudo apt-get -f check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
peter@pete:~$ apt-cache policy kde-workspace-data kdm
kde-workspace-data:
  Installed: 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
  Candidate: 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:4.11.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa3 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     4:4.11.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     4:4.10.5-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa2 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
     4:4.8.2a-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
kdm:
  Installed: 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3
  Candidate: 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
  Version table:
     4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
 *** 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:4.8.2a-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
peter@pete:~$ sudo apt-get install kde=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 kde-workspace-data=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins=4:4.11.kspace-data=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version ‘4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1’ for ‘kde’ was not found
peter@pete:~$ 
peter@pete:~$ apt-cache policy kde-workspace-data kdekde-workspace-data:
  Installed: 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
  Candidate: 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:4.11.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa3 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     4:4.11.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     4:4.10.5-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa2 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
     4:4.8.2a-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
kde:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

**UPDATE 4**

```
peter@pete:~$ sudo apt-get -f install kdm=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 kde-workspace-data=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kde-workspace-data is already the newest version.
kde-workspace-data set to manually installed.
kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins is already the newest version.
kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libkasten1controllers1 libnepomukdatamanagement4 libkface1 libkexiv2-10
  libkdegames5a libkipi8 libkggzgames4 libopencv-legacy2.3 ttf-dustin
  libkasten1okteta1core1 libkggznet4 libkggzmod4 libopencv-video2.3
  libkasten1okteta1gui1 libkasten1okteta1controllers1 libanalitza4abi1
  libkwinnvidiahack4 ktron libkdecorations4 libkwinglutils1 libkasten1core1
  rdesktop libboost-graph1.46.1 libnepomuksync4 libopenctl0.8 libokularcore1abi1
  libindi0 libkasten1gui1 kbattleship libplasmaclock4abi3 libkdcraw20
  libanalitzagui4abi1 libattica0.3 kdevplatform5-libs liblastfm0
  libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsublime5 libkwineffects1abi3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kdm
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,227 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,668 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdm:
 kdm depends on kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3); however:
  Version of kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins on system is 4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1.
 kde-workspace-data (4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1) breaks kdm (<< 4:4.10.80) and is installed.
  Version of kdm to be configured is 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3.
dpkg: error processing kdm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                         dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kubuntu-desktop:
 kubuntu-desktop depends on kdm; however:
  Package kdm is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing kubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 kdm
 kubuntu-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Updated question again.

Answer (score 1):

All your packages must be of the same version:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdm=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 kde-workspace-data=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
```

After that you should check again: `sudo apt-get check`. There shouldn't be any other error.

If for some motive the above solution didn't work, use `aptitude`:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude -f install
```

It should present you with a serie of possible solutions, select the one that uninstall no package and/or upgrade packages. I can't offer a example at this time.

---

Suspect: I'm believing that `kde-workspace-data` is too updated and could break things (kdm), but for some reason kdm isn't with the same version (darn PPA maintaners), so installing `4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3` and upgrading kdm should solve the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install kdm=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1 kde-workspace-data=4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3 kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins=4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1
```

Comment: Appreciated Braiams. Didn't go quite according to plan. Please see Update 3, with an extra diagnostic command after the command you instructed. I did do an `apt-get update` first.

Comment: I thought we had it then, but please see update 4. Sorry.

Comment: @PeterSnow ok, I have no idea what is happening so I will use heavy artillery.

Comment: lol. I'm beginning to think that I need to downgrade all KDE-* to `4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3` in order to get kdm and kde-desktop to configure and then figure out how to upgrade (possibly) afterwards. Not sure how to write the command to do the downgrade though using a wildcard?

Comment: If that's the case then the PPA is very broken and is not advisable using it. I was checking where is `kdm` package and know what... they don't have it. Just remove the ppa and let aptitude do it's work, look for a solution that doesn't uninstall half of your system...

Comment: Ok. Appreciate your help. I've just used ppa-purge to perform a rollback. Looks like it's going to uninstall most of KDE and apps, but I'm figuring I'll just re-install kde-full later after what I have is stable again.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Package is in a very bad inconsistent state, you should reinstall it by -

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install kubuntu-desktop
```

and restart once ,hope it will work.If not then disabling the kubuntu backports repository by going to `Software & Updates > Other Sources` then try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

now this time it will work.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that and got same message about unable to configure desktop because KDM is unconfigured. Tried to reinstall KDM but message says it can't be configured because KDM depends on `kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3)` but `4:4.11.3-0ubuntu0.1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1` is installed and breaks kdm (<< 4:4.10.80).

Comment: have you tested updates answer , means after removing..

Comment: I haven't removed the PPA yet, since that would be a last resort if nobody knows how to satisfy the dependencies.

Comment: dont remove just disable it, you can enable it after onwards whenever you want to..

Comment: How do I disable it please? There doesn't seem to be an option in `Software & Updates > Other Sources` to do that (only add, remove and edit).

Comment: just uncheck that...and "sudo apt-update"

Comment: I disabled it, did `update` then tried `sudo apt-get -f install` because when I tried upgrade it complained about broken packages and told me to run the above command, but the above command asked me to agree to remove `kdm` and `kubuntu-desktop` to fix the problem, both of which I need.

Comment: see in my answer i have mentioned to re-install it . it will not be solved without re installing it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11748/discussion-between-sushantp606-and-peter-snow)